# How to show a toast notification when the due date of the todo task is expired in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a todo app in which i am taking two input one is the todostring and other is a due date of the todo that is of type datetime-local.I want to show a toast notification whenever the due date of the todo is expired.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9raCv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use setTimeout() on the first render of the todo component.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => showToast(), expirationDate-currentDate);

  return () => { 
    clearTimeout(timeout) 
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

Comment: Thanks it worked for one item. I want to do this for every item in the todo array. i have attached the code. I tried using map it is not working.                                         useEffect(() => {
    var currentdate1 = new Date();
    var currentDate2 = new Date();
    {
      todos.map( todo => (
        <li key={todo.id}>
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => showToast(), expirationDate-currentDate);
        return () => { 
          clearTimeout(timeout) 
        };
        </li>
      )

      )
    }
  }, []);

Comment: @Hina You will want an array of timers, one for each todo that can expire. The cleanup function will need to iterate this array and call `clearTimeout` on each of them.